# describe odd number calculation

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, numerical-methods, arithmetic

**If a odd number 35**

two number addition 26 + 9 = 35

here small number 9 * 3 = 27

27 - 26 = 26 - 27 = +1 or -1

here 35 is the one of the odd number , 
from the odd number 35 which two number addition to get number 35 , 
and the two number full fill the above calculation , 
numbers are 26 and 9 addition to get 35 , 
small number 9 mul by 3 get 27 , 
small number is 9 and other big number 26 ,
(big number minus small number mul by 3) or (small number mul by 3 minus big number) to get ans +1 or -1

**another number 37**

two number addition 28 + 9 = 35

here small number 9 * 3 = 27

28 - 27 = 27 - 28 = +1 or -1

**another number 43**

two number addition 32 + 11 = 43

here small number 11 * 3 = 33

33 - 32 = 32 - 33 = +1 or -1

**and like above odd number is 55 how to get two number like above calculation any formula or method**

two number addition ? + ? = 55

here small number ? * ? = ?

? - ? = +1 or -1

**here how to get those two number , and those two number full fill the above calculation any formula or method need**

Comment: The formula for both is not the same. In one, you are adding $1$ to $27$ to get $28$. In the other you are subtracting $1$ from $27$ to get $26$. In my answer, will  I have to add or subtract the $1$?

Comment: It's not any more clear after you edited the question. If you are given *one* single number, say $35$, then you can't determine which *two* numbers added up to it, so you can't guess $26+9$. Back to the question, what is given, what are the rules, and what do you need to find?

Comment: Is $55 = 41+14$ where "*small number*" $14*3=42$ and $42-41=1$ what you are looking for?

Comment: Regarding your latest edit `small number is 9 and other big number 26, big number minus small number mul by 3 to get ans 1` but in the example you posted $26 - 9 \cdot 3 = -1 \ne 1$ so it's less and less clear what you are asking.

Comment: dxiv.  No,  "small number" is "odd number" x k = even number -1.  So 46 + 9=55;9 x 5=45; 46-45=1 is what the op has in mind.

Comment: @fleablood The original post has been edited several times. My previous reply was correct vs. the version in effect at the time I replied.

Comment: @dxiv  , your understand my question and your answer is correct , i need formula or method

Comment: The op doesn't indicate if the small number has to be the odd number or if it can be the even number.  The op also doesn't indicate if we must multiply by 3 or if we can multiply by any number.  In every case listed the "small number" was the odd number.  And in every case it was multiplied by 3.  It's really not clear.  It could be your answer or it could be mine.  Or it could be anyone elses.

Comment: Prabur, my understanding of the question is the same as posted by @Crostul in his answer. To solve it, note that if $n$ is odd, then exactly *one* of $n \pm 1$ is a multiple of $4$. For $n=55$ that's $55+1=56$, so $x = 56/4 = 14$. Then the second equation gives $y=41$.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is equivalent to finding a solution $(x,y)$ with $x < y$ of the following system:
$$\left\{ \begin{matrix} x&+&y& =& 55 \\
3x && \pm 1 & =& y\end{matrix} \right.$$
if you sum these two equations side by side, you can get an equation just with $x$ 
$$\left\{ \begin{matrix} 4x&& \pm 1& =& 55 \\
3x && \pm 1 & =& y\end{matrix} \right.$$
whose unique integer solution is $(x,y)=(14,41)$.

Comment: please explain more with example calculation

Comment: Have you ever seen a linear system? What do you find unclear?

Answer (score 0):

It was very hard to figure out what, if anything you were asking.

I finally figured you meant

$a + b = 55$ where $b $ is odd.

$b*c = a-1$

So $a-b*c=1$

Okay, we just solve it.

$a=55-b$

$b*c=54-b $

$b*(c+1)=54$

So $b $ can be $1,3,9,27$.

$54 +1 =55;1*53=53;54-53=1$

$52+3=55;3*17=51;52-51=1$

$46+9=55;9*5=45;46-45=1$

$28+27=55;27×1=27;28-27=1$

But, geez, it was practically impossible to guess what the heck you were trying to ask.  It seemed like you were completely making everything up.

I was going to answer just do $48+7=55; 3*6=18;17-16=1$.  That made about as much sense as your question seemed to.

====

More answers.  Seeing your latest post it seems you want:

$a + b =55;  a < b;a \le 22 $

$a*c = b \pm 1$

So $a*c =55 \pm 1 - a $

$a*(c+1)=54,56$

So $a= 1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,14,18, $

$b=54,53,51,etc. $

And $c=53,55,26,27,etc... $

Comment: I think the OP meant $c=3$ and $a \pm 1$ if you follow the sequence of comments and edits.

Comment: Maybe.  But it could be my way we're they odd number has to be in it.  Or maybe the op meant *both* and wants  a + odd = 55.  3*odd = a +/- 1.  In which case there is no solution.  The op did a TERRIBLE job explaining the question.